# Stylelint VScode doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, stylelint

I want to use the css linter "[stylelint](https://stylelint.io/)" on my VScode text editor. 
I downloaded the plugin and install it, then I make the "css.validate": false. But i don't have any box that show me error on my CSS files. What can I do ?

Comment: Have you followed each step of the [usage guidelines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shinnn.stylelint#user-content-usage), including enabling stylelint with `{ "stylelint.enable": true }`?

Comment: Yes and i found the solution.  I didin't have a stylelint.config.js file

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're getting started with stylelint *for the first time*, there are two key steps to enable it in Visual Studio Code:

1. turn off Visual Studio Code's built-in CSS linter and turn on the stylelint extension
2. create a stylelint [configuration object](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configuration/) and turn on some rules

You can complete the first step by following the [extension usage instructions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stylelint.vscode-stylelint), mainly changing your [Visual Studio Code settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) to:

```
{
  "stylelint.enable": true,
  "css.validate": false,
  "scss.validate": false
}
```

And the second step by following the [configuration documentation](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configuration/) on the stylelint website. I believe the quickest means to get started is:

1. install the recommended config into your project using npm:

`npm install --save-dev stylelint-config-recommended`

2. Create a `.stylelintrc` file that extends the recommended config in the root of your project:

`{ "extends": "stylelint-config-recommended" }`

This config turns on just the [possible error](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/#possible-errors) rules. It is a sensible config to start with and build upon. There are [over 150 rules](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/) built-in to stylelint. You can choose to turn on and configure as many, or as few, as you like to meet your linting needs.

Comment: The referenced VS Code extension no longer exists.

Comment: Hi, how can you declare a .stylelintrc file that is located in ./build subfolder ?

Comment: it works only if I put `{ "extends": "stylelint-config-recommended" }` in three lines and indent `"extends": "stylelint-config-recommended"`

Answer (score 4):

For anyone seeing this and trying to lint other file extensions; note that by default, [the extension validates only CSS and PostCSS files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stylelint.vscode-stylelint#only-css-and-postcss-are-validated-by-default).
In order to validate file extensions such as SCSS, you would need to explicitly state so in `.vscode\settings.json`:

```
{
  "css.validate": false,
  "less.validate": false,
  "scss.validate": false,
  "stylelint.enable": true,
  "stylelint.validate": ["css", "scss"]
}
```